# Domain Wide Cookies

Tags: cookies, httpwebrequest, cross-domain, session-cookies

I have `a.example.com` and it sets a cookie for `.example.com`. Later on `a.example.com` sends an ajax request to `b.example.com`. I expect the`.example.com` cookie to be sent to `b.example.com`. But it is not.

I made sure the cookie was set on the right domain, but it does not seem to send the cookie in the ajax request for some reason.

```
# server A
res.cookie('images', tokens.images, { expires: config.pageExpiration(), secure: secure, domain: domain })


# server B
req.cookies.image
```

Answer (score -2):

This makes sense, as you wouldn't expect *.com cookies to be mixed.
I suggest you pass your cookies through a server request if you really need to.

Comment: I meant *.example.com not *.com (I tried that one too, but it didn't work for obvious security reasons it is also specified in the spec that it should not work). But I should be able to set a domain-wide cookie and read it from arbitrary subdomains.